# JavaFX - javafx.beans.property update on background thread

Tags: java, javafx

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

@FXML
private TableView<Item> tableView;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Item, String> statusColumn;

private final ObservableList<Item> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Item());

@FXML
private void doThings() {
    new Thread(() -> items.get(0).updateStatus("New Status")).start();
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    tableView.setItems(items);
    statusColumn.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().status);
}

private class Item {

    public final StringProperty status;

    public Item() {
        status = new SimpleStringProperty("Idle");
    }

    public void updateStatus(String newStatus) {
        status.set(newStatus);
    }

}
```

}

Why am I able to update GUI from the background thread?

When I execute doThings() (it's connected to my gui button) I should get an IllegalStateException "Not on JavaFX main thread".
It doesn't occur. Why? Is it safe?

Comment: `It doesn't occur` -> I don't see where you are attempting to catch the error. `Why am I able to update GUI from the background thread?` -> It can happen but it's unpredictable behavior.

Comment: " I don't see where you are attempting to catch the error." I'm looking at the output of my application. " It can happen but it's unpredictable behavior." - I think that's the answer to my question

Comment: Users update the GUI all the time from other threads and they are always on here trying to figure out why their app is freezing or why it's acting funny.  Make sure you always update your app's GUI components on the application thread.

Comment: As you are seeing, some classes and methods enforce the application thread requirement, but not all strictly enforce it.  It’s up to us as programmers to make sure the code executes in the correct thread.  Of course, you are free to sprinkle your code with `assert Platform.isFxApplicationThread() : "Not in JavaFX application thread!";` as much as you wish;  it will incur no penalties.

Comment: the single most important fact you _must_ take care of: __DO-NOT__ modify any property of any node in the scenegraph off the fx application thread. Whether or not blowing when violating that rule immediately is irrelevant, it's introducing an instability that will blow sooner or later - and then be extremely hard to pin-point. BTW, Im pretty sure this is a duplicate of a recent question, can't find it right now .. will try tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

Like many UI toolkits JavaFX is essentially single threaded. You can only update UI state from the main JavaFX application thread.

JavaFX itself guards itself against updates from external threads in many places, *however this protection is not consistent*. Even though you may be able to "get away" with an external update in some cases this does not make it safe, other subtle problems may occur later.

You can place tasks onto the JavaFX application thread using [Platform.runLater()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-)

> Run the specified Runnable on the JavaFX Application Thread at some
>   unspecified time in the future. This method, which may be called from
>   any thread, will post the Runnable to an event queue and then return
>   immediately to the caller. The Runnables are executed in the order
>   they are posted. A runnable passed into the runLater method will be
>   executed before any Runnable passed into a subsequent call to
>   runLater. If this method is called after the JavaFX runtime has been
>   shutdown, the call will be ignored: the Runnable will not be executed
>   and no exception will be thrown.

So you'll need to do something like this...

```
public void updateStatus(String newStatus) {
    if (Platform.isFxApplicationThread()) {
        status.set(newStatus);
    } else {
        Platform.runLater(() -> status.set(newStatus));
    }
}
```

Comment: Like I said, the exception DOES NOT OCCUR. I AM ABLE TO UPDATE GUI WITHOUT ANY EXCEPTION

Comment: The question is asking why this isn’t always enforced.